# How to produce multiple plots from a multiple data sets

Tags: plotting

I have a number of lists and want to plot all of them vs each other. E.g.:

```
l={
{a,2,5,4,6},
{b,4,6,6,2},
{c,2,8,3,5},
{d,1,5,2,5}
}
```

Now I want multiple plots with
a vs b
a vs c
a vs d
b vs c
etc.

I know there is a function in Mathematica, which does exactly this – because I have used it before. Unfortunately I can't remember the function name and didn't find it in the help menu or here after extensive searching. So I hope someone can remind me of the function name – which I will immediately write down and never forget!

Comment: Are you thinking of Subsets?

Comment: No, its one simple command, such as xxxPlot[l] and you get all the plots.

Answer (score 9):

As said in the comment you can use `Subsets`!

```
l = {{a, 2, 5, 4, 6}, {b, 4, 6, 6, 2}, {c, 2, 8, 3, 5}, {d, 1, 5, 2,5}}; 
GraphicsGrid@Partition[
  ListLinePlot[dat = Transpose[#];Rest@dat, 
   FrameLabel -> First@dat, Mesh -> All, 
   MeshStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[.03]}}, Frame -> True] & /@ 
Subsets[l, {2}]), 3]
```

[image]

Comment: It is a nice solution, but I know there exists this command something like xxxPlot[l] and you instantly get all the diagrams.

Comment: OK, after about 3h searching I finally found it deep in the Mathematica help function:
PairwiseScatterPlot

Answer (score 5):

OK, I finally found it, after almost 3h of searching, thanks to everyone thinking about it!
Here it is:

```
Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]  
l = {{2, 5, 4, 6}, {4, 6, 6, 2}, {2, 8, 3, 5}, {1, 5, 2, 5}}  
PairwiseScatterPlot[l]
```

Comment: that is a good find..;)